# What happens if I manualy delete contents of trash folder in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I dropped a huge hive table, but hdfs space wasn't reclaimed. So i ran

```
hdfs dfs -expunge
```

The output was:

```
17/08/16 16:34:10 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: TrashPolicyDefault#deleteCheckpoint for trashRoot: hdfs://master.xxx.xx:8020/user/hdfs/.Trash
17/08/16 16:34:10 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: TrashPolicyDefault#deleteCheckpoint for trashRoot: hdfs://master.xxx.xx:8020/user/hdfs/.Trash
17/08/16 16:34:10 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: TrashPolicyDefault#createCheckpoint for trashRoot: hdfs://master.xxx.xx:8020/user/hdfs/.Trash
```

The result: HDFS space was still not reclaimed.
So I checked the contents of `/user/hdfs/.Trash`
and it was empty

Then I found, that the files to delete were in `/user/admin/.Trash`. Since I could not empty the trash, i deleted the contents of this folder manually via ambari Web-UI. Now the files are gone, but the space is still not reclaimed.

I have tried to set `fs.trash.interval` to 1 and rerun `hdfs dfs -expunge` with no result.

Is it just a matter of time until hdfs frees up?
What can I do to speed up this process?

**EDIT:**
output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report` is similar for all datanodes

```
Rack: /rack-2
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 411587164672 (383.32 GB)
DFS Used: 365118869504 (340.04 GB)
Non DFS Used: 2094696960 (1.95 GB)
DFS Remaining: 44373598208 (41.33 GB)
DFS Used%: 88.71%
DFS Remaining%: 10.78%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 2
```

**EDIT2**
After a while disk space has gone back on some hosts, but not on all. Can I expect the other hosts will too free their disk space?
[image: Ambari hosts]

Comment: `hdfs dfs -du -s -h /user/admin/.Trash` to check the disk usage of your Trash folder

Comment: A file in the Trash is just a file, that will be sent in the Trash, etc. Try to find where your huge files have been moved the 2nd time (cf. `hdfs dfs -find` by name) then **drop them once and for good** with `hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash`

Comment: hdfs dfs -du -s -h /user/admin/.Trash:  
`0  /user/admin/.Trash`

Comment: addidtionally i searched for the biggest file on hdfs and it was one in my current hive warehouse, so not the trash files that were way bigger